# Android 5 disable install button of apk files on nexus 4

Tags: apk, android-versions

After updating my nexus 4 to new android 5 (lollipop) when i open an apk file, the install button not working!!
Also i checked unknown source in my device settings.

What the problem? please help :(

Answer (score 1):

I have used lux lite application, this application set display brighness for reading in night mode. my problem solved when i unistall this app.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have apps that interfere with the installation. 
Example: I used to have Avast on my phone. Every now and then I couldn't install an app for the problem you're describing. 
I uninstalled Avast (but just disabling it would be fine) and everything went fine. 
So this is it: look at the apps already installed in your phone. Chances are there is something that blocks the installation...